# Getting around multiple iterations of integration by parts

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing a differential equation that requires the integrating factor.

The original equation is: $$\frac{dy}{dx}+10x^4y=50x^9e^{3x^{5}} $$

I can get the equation to this form:   $$e^{2x^{5}}y=\int 10x^{9}e^{5x^{5}}\mathrm{d}x$$

I see integration by parts is required by the RHS. My question is there any way of getting around doing so many times. You do it once and end up with another integration by parts, and as far as I can tell its not cyclical so you cannot subtract it. I have looked online as seen that people combine u-sub with by parts. I never really learned the proper way to do that or the situations in which it applies. Could anybody give me some pointers? Thanks.

Comment: Please consider accepting any one of the 2 answers if you found them helpful. You can do so by clicking on the checkmark next to either of the answers

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify your integral on the RHS to a simple by-part integration like this:

$$\int 10 x^9 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{5x^5} \mathrm{d}x$$
$$=2\cdot \int5x^4 \cdot x^5 \cdot \mathrm{e}{^{5x^5}} \mathrm{d}x$$
Substitute $x^5=t$
$$=2\int t\cdot \mathrm{e}^{5t}\mathrm{d}t$$
This should be easy to solve from here

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+10x^4y=50x^9e^{3x^{5}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx^5}\frac{dx^5}{dx}+10x^4y=50x^9e^{3x^{5}}$$
$$5{x^4}\frac{dy}{du}+10yx^4=50x^9e^{3x^{5}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{du}+2y=10ue^{3u}$$
Your differential equation is equivalent to:
$$y'+2y=10ue^{3u}$$
Where $u=x^5$. You integrate once by part the R.H.S and you're done.